# PHP setlocale string

Tags: php, locale

In PHP I was setting my locale like this:

```
// I simplified code, actually there exists 20 different locales and system selects proper language
$myArray=array('de_DE.utf8', 'de_DE' );
$localeData = "'" . implode("', '", $myArray) . "'";
// $localeData = "'de_DE.utf8', 'de_DE'"
setlocale(LC_TIME, $localeData);
```

This was working up to now. After hours of debugging I found out that this works:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.utf8', 'de_DE');
```

Does setlocale's behaviour changed ?
It was easier to set locale as a long string.
But now how can I make setlocale ?
I need to pass every value as a parameter to setlocale ?

(I use PHP 5.4.30 in Apache 2 and Centos 6.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get each value to a seperate variable with this code

```
$myArray = array('de_DE.utf8', 'de_DE' );
list($a, $b) = $myArray;
echo $a; //de_DE.utf8
echo $b; //de_DE
```

Now you can do it like this

`setlocale(LC_TIME, $a, $b);`

Also it should be fine passing the array directly to setlocale like this.

`setlocale(LC_TIME, $myArray);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php